# Отправка формы с использованием ajax(jquery)

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Не отправляются данные на почту.

Сама форма выглядит так:

```
<form id="form" class="main_form" novalidate>
    <div class="range-wrap">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="range-slider">
                <div class="label-range">Хронометраж видеоролика, сек.<br>
                    <span>длина ролика в секундах</span>
                </div>
                <input id="range3" type="range" name="range3" min="20" max="180" step="1" value="20">
                <p>Хронометраж ролика: <span id="demo"></span></p>
                <div class="label-range">
                    Тип видео<br>
                    <span>выберите необходимый формат видеоролика</span>
                </div>
                <div class="radios">
                    <input type="radio" name="yesno" value="Рекламный" id="radio_0" tabindex="4"
                        checked="checked">
                    <label for="radio_0">Рекламный</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="yesno" value="Имиджевый" id="radio_1" tabindex="5">
                    <label for="radio_1">Имиджевый</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="yesno" value="Ролик для соцсетей" id="radio_2" tabindex="6">
                    <label for="radio_2">Ролик для соцсетей</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="yesno" value="Презентация" id="radio_3" tabindex="7">
                    <label for="radio_3">Презентация</label>
                </div>
                <div class="label-range">Дополнительные опции:<br>
                    <span>выберите, какие дополнительные услуги нужны</span>
                </div>
                <div class="checkboxes">
                    <input id="a" name="check[]" type="checkbox" value="Диктор" tabindex="1">
                    <label class="green-background" for="a">Диктор</label>
                    <input id="b" name="check[]" type="checkbox" value="Актер, модель" tabindex="2">
                    <label class="green-background" for="b">Актер, модель</label>
                    <input id="c" name="check[]" type="checkbox" value="Студия" tabindex="3">
                    <label class="green-background" for="c">Студия</label>
                    <input id="d" name="check[]" type="checkbox" value="Другое" tabindex="4">
                    <label class="green-background" for="d">Другое</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="range-slider">
                <div class="label-range">Срок изготовления ролика, день<br>
                    <span>выберите кол-во дней на изготовление ролика</span>
                </div>
                <input id="range4" type="range" name="range4" min="0" max="30" step="1" value="0" >
                <p>Ролик нужен через: <span id="demo1"></span></p>

                <div class="label-range">Графика<br>
                    <span>выберите необходимый объем и сложность графики</span>
                </div>
                <div class="radios">
                    <input type="radio" name="noyes" value="Нет графики" id="radio_4" tabindex="0"
                        checked="checked">
                    <label for="radio_4">Нет графики</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="noyes" value="Простая" id="radio_5" tabindex="1">
                    <label for="radio_5">Простая</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="noyes" value="Сложная" id="radio_6" tabindex="2">
                    <label for="radio_6">Сложная</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="noyes" value="3D-графика" id="radio_7" tabindex="3">
                    <label for="radio_7">3D-графика</label>
                </div>
                <div class="calc-form">
                <label class="form-group">
                    <span class="color_element">*</span> Ваше имя:
                    <input class="input_popup" type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя"
                            data-validation-required-message="Вы не ввели имя" required>
                </label>
                <label class="form-group">
                    <span class="color_element">*</span> Ваш E-mail:
                    <input class="input_popup" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Ваш E-mail"
                        data-validation-required-message="Не корректно введен E-mail" required>
                </label>
                <label class="form-group">
                    <span class="color_element">*</span> Ваш Телефон(без "8"):
                    <input class="input_popup" type="tel" id="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Ваш номер телефона"
                        data-validation-required-message="Не корректно введен номер" required>
                </label>
                <label class="form-group">
                    Ваше сообщение:
                    <textarea class="input_popup" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Введите ваше сообщение" cols="10" rows="3"></textarea>
                </label>
                <input id="e" type="checkbox" tabindex="5">
                <label class="agree" for="e">Я даю согласие на обработку <a href="https://maneev-video.ru/privacy-policy/">Персональных данных</a> </label>
                
                    <div class="ccd">
                        <button type="button" id="SendMailCalc">Отправить</button>
                        <div id="errorMess"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</form>
```

Есть ajax запрос:

```
"use strict";
$("#SendMailCalc").on("click", function() {

    let name = $("#name").val().trim();
    let email = $("#email").val().trim();
    let tel = $("#tel").val().trim();
    let message = $("#message").val().trim();
    let range3 = $("#range3");
    let range4 = $("#range4");
    // let yesno = $("#radio_" + $(this)).val().trim();
    // let noyes = $("#radio_" + $(this)).val().trim();
    let r1 = range3.val();
    let r2 = range4.val();
    
    if(name == ""){
        $("#errorMess").text("Введите Имя");
        return false;
    }
    if(email == ""){
        $("#errorMess").text("Введите Email");
        return false;
    }
    if(tel == ""){
        $("#errorMess").text("Введите телефон");
        return false;
    } else if(message.length < 5){
        $("#errorMess").text("Введите сообщение не менее 5 символов");
    }

    $("#errorMess").text("");
    
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/callback_calculator.php',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: 'false',
        data: {'name': name, 'email': email, 'tel': tel, 'message': message, 'range3': r1, 'range4': r2 },
        dataType: 'html',
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#SendMailCalc").prop("disabled", true);
        },
        success: function(data){
            if(!data){
                alert("ERROR");
            }
            else{
                $("#form").trigger("reset");
                $("#errorMess").text("Сообщение успешно отправлено");
            }
            $("#SendMailCalc").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });

});
```

Также есть PHP отправка:

```
<?php
    $site_name = "Maneev Video";
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $range3 = $_POST['range3'];
    $range4 = $_POST['range4'];

    if(isset($_POST["yesno"])){
        $yesno = $_POST["yesno"];
    }


    if(isset($_POST["noyes"])){
        $noyes = $_POST["noyes"];
    }

    if(isset($_POST["check"])){
     
        $check = $_POST["check"];
    }

    $subject = "=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode("Сообщение с сайта \"$site_name\"")."?=";
    $headers = "От кого: INFO@MANEEV-VIDEO.RU\r\nКому: $email\r\nТелефон: $tel\r\n;

    $success = mail("and1marat9@gmail.com", $subject, $headers, $message, $range3, $range4, $yesno, $noyes, $check);
    echo $success;
?>
```

Выходит такая ошибка:

```
jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4 POST ajax/callback_calculator.php 500
send @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ SendMailCalc.js:31
dispatch @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:3
```

Не получается разобраться, в чем проблема. Может тут кто-то помочь сможет...

Comment: лог пхп посмотрите, там будет написано в чем ошибка

Comment: Угу, соглашусь с предыдущим комментарием. 500 - ошибка на стороне сервера

Comment: эту ошибку вроде исправил изменением url, теперь выводит alert("error");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В строке забыли закрыть кавычку:

```
$headers = "От кого: INFO@MANEEV-VIDEO.RU\r\nКому: $email\r\nТелефон: $tel\r\n"; // вот здесь
```

Ну да, если посмотреть на вашу функцию mail() там как-то слишком много параметров, согласно [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php) должно быть 5:

```
 mail(
    string $to,
    string $subject,
    string $message,
    array|string $additional_headers = [],
    string $additional_params = ""
): bool
```

в Вашем же примере их было 9-ть.

Так же Вы спутали все местами, $message -- третий параметр, у Вас вместо этого $headers, должно быть:

```
$success = mail("and1marat9@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Все Ваши дополнительные чекбоксы и рейнджы нужно сконкатинировать в $message чтобы это пришло в теле письма.

Comment: Исправил, спасибо)
Но проблему не решило, если сам найду ошибку, сюда дам ответ

Comment: @МаратАбзалов так там до сих пор 500 или уже какая-то другая ошибка?

Comment: Я убрал строчки в php: 
```// if(isset($yesno){
    //     $yesno1 = $_POST['yesno'];
    // }


    // if(isset($noyes){
    //     $noyes1 = $_POST['noyes'];
    // }

    // if(isset($_POST['check'])){
     
    //     $check = $_POST['check'];
    // }
```
Теперь пишет, что сообщение успешно отправлено, но на почту ничего не приходит

Comment: @МаратАбзалов обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, вы помогли мне очень!